# Kendo window.refresh not successfully grabbing partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-window

all. Thank you in advance.

I have a window which much refresh every time a dropdown selection is changed (or button is pressed). The *controller* is being called upon refresh, but the *view* is not being called/refreshed, for some reason. Am I missing something fundamental?

Window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("EditWindow")
    .Title("Edit Contact")
    .LoadContentFrom("_ContactEdit", "Contacts", new { selectedContact = Model.ContactId })
    .Content("Loading...")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(true)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
)
```

Refresh code (in javascript):

```
    var combobox = $("#ContactId").data("kendoComboBox");
    var ContactId = combobox.value();
    var window = $("#EditWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    window.refresh({
        url: "../../Contacts/_ContactEdit",
        data: { selectedContact: ContactId }
        //url: "/Contacts/_ContactEdit/?selectedContact=ContactId"
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _ContactEdit(int selectedContact)
{
    var entities = from r in dbContext.Contacts
                   where r.ContactId == selectedContact
                   select r;
    if (entities.Any())
    { return PartialView(entities.First()); }
    else
    { return HttpNotFound("Contact does not exist."); }
}
```

I know that the partial view is working correctly because it's called and populates upon the initial window load. Why in the world can't I get it to refresh?

*edit*: Here's my partial view (window contents):

```
@model PNC.CM.MBS.BizServiceTier.IIDB.Contact
@using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset id="infoForm">Hello, world.
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactId, new { id = "EditWindowId" })
        <br />
        <label id ="ContactNameID" style="width: 130px;">Contact Name</label>
        <span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { type = "text", id = "EditWindowName", @class = "k-textbox form-control", style = "width: 200px; cursor:default" })
        </span><br />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Why are you using dots in your url? Shouldn't it be `"/Contacts/_ContactEdit"`?

Comment: @Brett, that was my first try (without dots). The dots were an attempt to force the code to find the controller. It doesn't work in either scenario :/

Comment: Use F12 developer tools and look at the network tab. What url is your browser actually calling? Do you get a 404? If so, correct it to what it needs to be. Use the fully qualified url if you need to.

Comment: @Brett, unfortunately, since I'm using partial views I'm not sure I can use a fully-qualified URL? I *do* know that the controller is being hit, which makes me think that I'm successfully coding the URL, at least.

Comment: If your controller is being hit, then the URL is ok. It might be that the Kendo UI Window doesn't know what to do with the data you're returning. Try setting `Iframe(true)` in the configuration of the window.

Comment: Hm. That didn't work - it just changed what the window looks like. I think I may not understand how to code my window (I'm adding the code above). When I refresh the window, does the partial view get the new information from the controller? That's what I want, correct? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab of your browser's development tools (F12)? Are there any errors highlighted there or in the console? It might help to know what format the data returned from the server looks like. I assume `PartialView` is serialized as a string when it's sent to the client.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution for this problem? I'm also struggling with this issue. Thanks Sven