# Kendo window refresh does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I am stuck at what appears to be a very simple scenario: 
Loading a Kendo window with a partial view bound to a model, with a dynamic parameter `modelId` that will be provided by client side js.

I found out about the `refresh()` method, but this implies that there is already a kendo window intialized. That's the first problem. I need the the `modelId` to display content.
So I worked around this issue and simply returned a new model intially which than should be replaced/refreshed by the `refresh()` method + a valid parameter `modelId` and finally be displayed.
Problem: The view won't be updated.
The `refresh()` method actually works, though.
The controller receives the parameter `modelId`, fetches the corresponding model and returns the view. But the Kendo window still holds the empty viewmodel instead.

I tryed really hard to get this to work but without success..

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
      .Name("window")
      .Title("")
    //loads an empty viewmodel intially as there is no possibility to pass parameter
      .LoadContentFrom("Actionname", "Controller")          
      .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
      .Modal(true).Visible(false)
      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "margin: 10px"})
      )
```

Javascript snippet:

```
$("#window").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
    url: '/controller/actionname/',
    data: { parameterlabel: parameter}
});
$("#window").data("kendoWindow").open().center(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your main issue, but you should be able to do this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("")
    .LoadContentFrom("Actionname", "Controller", new { modelID = modelId })          
    .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
    .Modal(true).Visible(false)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "margin: 10px"})
)
```

Then you won't need to load the empty model and refresh it with the correct parameter.

Comment: Okay thx. But how is this different? I don't expect the refresh() method to react different this way. Is there really now way to pass parameters intially? And why isn't the refresh() working? Thx for helping!

Comment: ..I just found another topic that seems to be related but there is also no real conclusion.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323213/kendo-window-refresh-not-successfully-grabbing-partial-view

Comment: ..could it be that I got it wrong and the refresh() method acutally doesn't need a fully loaded kendo window with content in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

..could it be that I got it wrong and the refresh() method acutally doesn't need a fully loaded kendo window with content in the first place? I found this on teleriks page: "
If you want to load content in the window dynamically (through AJAX), you can do so by:

```
//set up kendo window
$(document).ready(function () {
     var window = $("#window").kendoWindow({
         height: "200px",
         modal: true,
         title: "Centered Window",
         visible: false,
         width: "200px"

     }).data("kendoWindow");
 });
//using the refresh method after the window has been intialized:
var dialog = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
dialog.refresh({
    url: "/search",
    data: { query: "foobar" }
}); "
```

.. not excaclty what I'd expect of a refresh but okay..
So maybe I should just remove the load content in the created kendo window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("window")
.Title("")
//.LoadContentFrom("Actionname", "Controller", new { modelID = modelId })          
.Actions(actions => actions.Close())
.Modal(true).Visible(false)
.HtmlAttributes(new {style = "margin: 10px"})
)
```

Comment: This helped me.  I found that removing the LoadContentFrom meant that I could reload (refresh) the window with different data

Answer (score 1):

First time I saw this issue with:

```
wnd.refresh({
    url: msg.Url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json", 
    dataType: "json",
    data: msg.Data
});
```

and the Kendo Window was empty. The request in Fiddler (some headers and data removed):

```
POST http://localhost/My/PtsSchedule/Pts_AddBooking HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
```

The problem was apparently in:

> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

and removing dataType: solved the issue for me. Here the new refresh:

```
wnd.refresh({
    url: msg.Url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json", 
    data: msg.Data
});
```

and in Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost/My/PtsSchedule/Pts_AddBooking HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
```

and the content was displayed within the Kendo Window. Hope this is from help.

Comment: I had the same:
with datatype: 'json' my Kendo window keeps showing the spinning progress (but the content is actually loaded behind (view in chrome response))

but when I remove the datatype: 'json' the progress bar is gone and the data is showed